# Drools workbench 7.12.0 for Tomcat

Tags: workbench, drools-guvnor

I am new to Drools and am trying to install drools server and workbench 7.12.0. I happen to see see a tomcat version of the war for the workbench in the previous versions but not for 7.12.0. Can someone point me to the right war to be used for Tomcat?

I checked the documentation, its says a tailored version of the war is available but I could not find one.

Best Regards,
Hanmanth.

Comment: yes, i too saw it in the documentation. however not able to find the war. Can you share if you find a solution?. Thak you

Answer (score 1):

As per clarification [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/drools-setup/kazWLjBwOZ4/) , it appears support for tomcat is dropped, until there are folks who want to maintain it.

You can switch over to wildfly (community) version of kie-workbench.